# Connect to access 2010 using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, ms-access-2010

How can I connect to ab Access 2010 database with the Entity Framwork? Connecting to SQL Server is so easy but I can't use Access database.

Thank anyway for your help

Comment: why do you want to to use access? Do you want to read from an existing access file? or do you just want a standalone database, because if that's the case I'd suggest you to use [system.data.sqlite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)

Comment: i should to use a simple data base.i dont want to istall sql server on the Customer Machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access is not natively supported in EntityFramework, you will need to find a third party provider written for Access but the last time I checked there was none.